# Iterate through object, property gets undefined strangely

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm banging my head against the desk right now.
I simply can't understand **why** I can't iterate through my JSON object when I clearly can see the object when I use `console.log()`.

This is my current loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < list[i].information.locations.length; y++) {
    if (list[i].information.locations[y].city !== '') {
      newArr.push({
        "city": list[i].information.locations[y].city,
        "country": list[i].information.locations[y].country
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'locations' of undefined`

But as you can see from the screenshot of my terminal I clearly have the information object and the locations array with objects within.

[image]

If I try to do: `console.log(list[i].information);` within the first `for` loop I get only `undefined` as result.

The main problem is that I seem have list[i].information undefined or something. But I think it is defined, because I can see it when I do the large console.log of my entire array with objects.

Anyone know why this is happening?
Tyvm.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(list[i])` ?

Comment: did you convert JSON to object using JSON.parse() ?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be in the code you posted. Maybe a timing problem? I mean that when you loop the array, objects are not there, but after some time (maybe after an ajax call completes) objects are there...

Comment: Seeing just a partial output of the whole array is not very useful if the error occurs right at the first element – if the first element doesn't have the property, it doesn't matter how many other elements have it. What does `console.log(list[0])` show? What about `console.log(typeof list[0])`?

Comment: @Juhana the two lines: `console.log(list[0]);` `console.log(typeof list[0]);` generates the following in my terminal: `{ _id: 57348c26c0c43f5be9b2cd39,
  information: { locations: [ [Object] ] } }
object` so in my opinion everything seems to be ok. When I write: `console.log(list[0].information` and also the same with typeof I get `undefined` for both.

Comment: Just take the full JSON object, put it in a pastebin, and show it to us. It will make this whole thing a lot easier.

Comment: @MatisLepik http://pastebin.com/6FRGDQ2h

Comment: Worth to mention is that I also use the __async__ library so it isn't an timing issue as @FrancescoD'Alesio suggested..

Comment: @LucasReppeWelander As mentioned, issue is one of the object does not have property information. So when you try to access `information.location.length` it fails. [Check this Fiddle Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but useful for others to know.

My `.information` object was undefined because my mongoose Model didn't include it at the time I wrote this question.

I think this is really strange because I could clearly see it in my array but it wasn't defined as in code. but it was in the terminal.

I just added `"information": {}` and the other stuff inside it to my model and everything worked like a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, your code is breaking at this line:

```
for (var y = 0; y < list[i].information.locations.length; y++)
```

If there is an object inside list that does not have same structure, it will break.

[Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/)

You should try something like this:

```
var len = list[i].information && list[i].information.locations? list[i].information.locations.length: 0;
for (var y = 0; y < len; y++) {
```

[Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/1/).

Comment: This didnt made it work, I think it don't work because my `list[i].information` returns as `undefined`, so it just doesn't go in into that last foor loop.

Comment: @LucasReppeWelander Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/2/). Its not throwing error anymore.

Comment: No it doesnt, but neither does it push anything to the array called newArr. Look at both this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3nsmeuz/4/ and this: https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/2/ the second one is yours where I just console.logged out he newArr array..

Comment: @LucasReppeWelander Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/u3nsmeuz/6/) fiddle. Your fiddle was throwing error because, `var list = x.companyLocations;` here `x` is an array. Try `x[0]` instead.